# Why the maxValue + 1 of an int is the same as maxValue, but not for shorts and bytes?

Tags: java, types, range, primitive-types

I was experiencing Java primitive types ranges, and I came up with a small confusion, here is some line of code that illustrates clearly what is it about:

```
System.out.println((byte) (Math.pow(2, 7))+1); //the maximum value + 1 overflows to the minimum value
System.out.println((short) (Math.pow(2, 15)-1)); //same for shorts
System.out.println((int) Math.pow(2, 31)); 
System.out.println((int) (Math.pow(2, 31)+1)); //returns the maximum value of the int range
System.out.println((int) (Math.pow(2, 31)+100)); //returns the maximum value of the int range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.pow returns double, therefore you add +1 to double value and than cast it to int, short or byte. But this part is already covered by other answers.

There is another interesting thing about your example. Differences of casting double to decimal types.

You have differences in bracketing. And `-` sing instead of `+` in `short` line.

Fixed them for you(to always cast at the end):

```
    System.out.println((byte) (Math.pow(2, 7)+1)); //the maximum value + 1 overflows to the minimum value
    System.out.println((short) (Math.pow(2, 15)+1)); //same for shorts
    System.out.println((int) Math.pow(2, 31));
    System.out.println((int) (Math.pow(2, 31)+1)); //returns the maximum value of the int range
    System.out.println((int) (Math.pow(2, 31)+100)); //returns the maximum value of the int range
```

Result:

```
-127
-32767
2147483647
2147483647
2147483647
```

Now everything except int overflows. And here is why.

From 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html about conversions of double to decimal types:

`The results for char, int, and long are unsurprising, producing the minimum and maximum representable values of the type.`

`The results for byte and short lose information about the sign and magnitude of the numeric values and also lose precision. The results can be understood by examining the low order bits of the minimum and maximum int. The minimum int is, in hexadecimal, 0x80000000, and the maximum int is 0x7fffffff. This explains the short results, which are the low 16 bits of these values, namely, 0x0000 and 0xffff; it explains the char results, which also are the low 16 bits of these values, namely, '\u0000' and '\uffff'; and it explains the byte results, which are the low 8 bits of these values, namely, 0x00 and 0xff.`

Also note: `+1` is unnecessary in examples. `(byte) (0b10000000)` equals -128 and other types act analogously.

Answer (score 6):

```
Math.pow(2, 7)
```

is `128.0`, which is more than can fit in a `byte`. When you cast, it becomes `-128`. Add 1 and it becomes `-127`.

The same behavior applies to your `short` example.

As for the `int` example, you should apply the `(int)` cast before you do your addition `+`. In your current case, the `+` happens with a `double` and an `int`. Numeric promotion happens on the `int` to convert it to a `double`. Then it's just a matter of precision.

```
System.out.println(Math.pow(2,31) + 1);
```

prints

```
2.147483649E9
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't. `MAX_VALUE` + 1 will overflow to `MIN_VALUE`, for example

```
int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
if (i + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
    System.out.println("MAX_VALUE + 1 == MIN_VALUE");
}
```

Outputs

```
MAX_VALUE + 1 == MIN_VALUE
```

Of course, your code seems like it is because you cast from double to int.

```
System.out.println((int) (1 + (double) Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

Will also appear to be MAX_VALUE, because the code explicitly narrows the type.

Comment: because `System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE == (int) (Math.pow(2, 31)));` returns true, the problem I'm facing is more weird now

Comment: @initParam In what way? Java primitive types are signed.